# FLUTTER JUST_AUDIO Navigator.Push not working when finished play

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the package Just_Audio. It's been working well, However now I want that when it finished playing if the user hasn't paid a Payment screen should open.

Here is the code:

```
void closeScreen() {


final _userHasPaid =
    Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).user.testPaid;
print("USER PAID = ${_userHasPaid}");
if (_userHasPaid == false && widget.breathwork.breathType == "F") {
  print("got here");
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        print(" and got here");
        return PaymentsScreen();
      },
    ),
  );
}

disposeAudio();
print("should pop now");
Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

Before I introduced the Navigator.push it all worked fine and close the screen with the Navigator.pop. However as soon as I add the push code, I do not get the PaymentsScreen and also the Navigator.pop at the end is no longer working.

I do see prints to the console for :
print USER PAID
print got here
print should pop now

But not for:
print got here.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't call both Navigator.push and pop function at the same time, you have to go to payment page then you have to pop from there once the payment is done, and add the disposeAudio(); function before push to payment page

```flutter
void closeScreen() {

disposeAudio();

final _userHasPaid =
    Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).user.testPaid;
print("USER PAID = ${_userHasPaid}");
if (_userHasPaid == false && widget.breathwork.breathType == "F") {
  print("got here");
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        print(" and got here");
        return PaymentsScreen();
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes it clearer. But I do need to pop. I don't want to return to this screen, after the payment is finished, but the screen before it.

Comment: you can push into that screen from here